# Why does gcc ignore __attribute__((stdcall))?

Tags: c, gcc, calling-convention

When I compile the following C source with `gcc` version 8.1.1, I get a `warning: ‘stdcall’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]`.

Why does gcc choose to ignore this attribute and what can I do to make it accept it?

```
__attribute__((stdcall)) int S(int a) {
    return a * (a+1);
}

int main() {
    return S(6);
}
```

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for?

Comment: Move to a 32-bit x86 platform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-force_005falign_005farg_005fpointer-function-attribute_002c-x86) says:

> `stdcall`
>
> **On x86-32 targets**, the `stdcall` attribute causes the compiler to assume that the called function pops off the stack space used to pass arguments, unless it takes a variable number of arguments.

(Emphasis mine.)

So if you're not compiling for a 32-bit machine, `stdcall` can't be used.

Comment: Is there a technical reason that stdcall is not possible on non-x86-32 targets?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger x86-64 [doesn't pass arguments on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) (or rather, it prefers using registers before using the stack), so there's little point in defining and using different incompatible conventions for adjusting the stack.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up to me. I was completely unaware of the shift between 32 and 64 bit x86 regarding calling conventions.

Comment: Is it possible to turn this warning off?